# How to create chart with clickable bar using chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, onclick, chart.js

We need a chart with the ability to click on bar in this chart
and on click display element (div) and display data on this div using HTML and jquery

```js
var xyValues = [
  {x:50, y:7},
  {x:60, y:8},
  {x:70, y:8},
  {x:80, y:9},
  {x:90, y:9},
  {x:100, y:9},
  {x:110, y:10},
  {x:120, y:11},
  {x:130, y:14},
  {x:140, y:14},
  {x:150, y:15}
];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "scatter",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,255)",
      data: xyValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 40,
          max: 160
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 6,
          max: 16
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add `onClick` option in the chart options.

The option accepts a function as value.

Here is the doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/general/interactions/events.html

```
  options: {
    onClick(event, clickedElemeents) {
      .... your logic
    },
    legend: {display: false},
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ticks: {min: 40, max:160}}],
      yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:16}}],
    }
  }
```

Comment: I need every bar in chart tack action by some input

Comment: clickedElements contains all elements "clicked" therefore you can do what ever is needed based on element or data you provide to the chart. You can add to  xyValues objects your properties to reuse in the click